# Pandas - Add List to multiple columns (for multiple rows)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of values that I want to update into multiple columns, this is fine for a single row. However when I try to update over multiple rows it simply overrides the whole column with the last value.

List for each row looks like below (note: list length is of variable size):

```
['2016-03-16T09:53:05',
 '2016-03-16T16:13:33',
 '2016-03-17T13:30:31',
 '2016-03-17T13:39:09',
 '2016-03-17T16:59:01',
 '2016-03-23T12:20:47',
 '2016-03-23T13:22:58',
 '2016-03-29T17:26:26',
 '2016-03-30T09:08:17']
```

I can store this in empty columns by using:

```
for i in range(len(trans_dates)):
    df[('T' + str(i + 1) + ' - Date')] = trans_dates[i]
```

However this updates the whole column with the single `trans_dates[i]` value

I thought looping over each row with the above code would work but it still overwrites.

```
for issues in all_issues:
    for i in range(len(trans_dates)):
        df[('T' + str(i + 1) + ' - Date')] = trans_dates[i]
```

- **How do I only update my current row in the loop?**
- **Am I even going about this the right way? Or is there a faster vectorised way of doing it?**

Full code snippet below:

```
for issues in all_issues:
    print(issues)
    changelog = issues.changelog
    trans_dates = []
    from_status = []
    to_status = []
    for history in changelog.histories:
        for item in history.items:
            if item.field == 'status':
                trans_dates.append(history.created[:19])
                from_status.append(item.fromString)
                to_status.append(item.toString)
    trans_dates = list(reversed(trans_dates))
    from_status = list(reversed(from_status))
    to_status = list(reversed(to_status))
    print(trans_dates)

    # Store raw data in created columns and convert dates to pd.to_datetime
    for i in range(len(trans_dates)):
        df[('T' + str(i + 1) + ' - Date')] = trans_dates[i]
    for i in range(len(to_status)):
        df[('T' + str(i + 1) + ' - To')] = to_status[i]
    for i in range(len(from_status)):
        df[('T' + str(i + 1) + ' - From')] = from_status[i]
    for i in range(len(trans_dates)):
        df['T' + str(i + 1) + ' - Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['T' + str(i + 1) + ' - Date'])
```

- **EDIT: Sample input and output added.**

input:
issue/row #1 list (note year changes):

```
    ['2016-03-16T09:53:05',
     '2016-03-16T16:13:33',
     '2016-03-17T13:30:31',
     '2016-03-17T13:39:09']
```

issue #2

```
['2017-03-16T09:53:05',
 '2017-03-16T16:13:33',
 '2017-03-17T13:30:31']
```

issue #3

```
['2018-03-16T09:53:05',
 '2018-03-16T16:13:33',
 '2018-03-17T13:30:31']
```

issue #4

```
['2015-03-16T09:53:05',
 '2015-03-16T16:13:33']
```

output:

```
        col       T1                     T2                      T3                 T4
        17 '2016-03-16T09:53:05'   '2016-03-16T16:13:33'  '2016-03-17T13:30:31'  '2016-03-17T13:30:31'
        18 '2017-03-16T09:53:05'   '2017-03-16T16:13:33'  '2017-03-17T13:30:31'  np.nan
        19 '2018-03-16T09:53:05'   '2018-03-16T16:13:33'  '2018-03-17T13:30:31' np.nan
        20 '2015-03-16T09:53:05'   '2015-03-16T16:13:33'      np.nan     np.nan
```

Comment: Can you post a sample input and expected output?

Comment: Added to main question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
for i in range(len(trans_dates)):
    df[('T' + str(i + 1) + ' - Date')] = trans_dates[i]
```

Try this:

```
for i in range(len(trans_dates)):
    df.loc[i, ('T' + str(i + 1) + ' - Date')] = trans_dates[i]
```

There are probably better ways to do this... `df.merge` or `df.replace` come to mind... it would be helpful if you posted what the input dataframe looked like and what the expected result is.